# How to get rid the horrible rectangle arround <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website and everywhere i have this annoying problem... I wonder how other sites dont have this problem... any suggestion?
stackoverflow has this problem as i see...
http://inath.gr/ this site for example at the top menu although it has `<a>` tags there is no rectangle arround it when selected somehow..

Comment: You're killing users who navigate by keyboard. Consider giving the `outline` a less disturbing color instead of completely removing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[CSS outline property](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_outline.asp):

You can turn it off with:

```
<style type = "text/css">
    a {outline:0;} /*this is that dotted line you get when you select an image, I believe you're talking about the outline*/
    a img {border:0;} /*Images in links default to having a blue border, so this could be the source of another annoying rectangle*/
</style>
```

Comment: Yeah in 8 minutes, it doesnt allow me

Comment: For completeness I've added the a img {border:0;} as well for people who stumble across this for the other common reason you'll see a rectangular border around image links.

Answer (score 2):

The following is considered better because it allows users to still navigate by keyboard.

Here is a link explaining why:
http://people.opera.com/patrickl/experiments/keyboard/test

```
a:hover, a:active { outline: none; }
```